# How can clear ImageButton's background?

Tags: android, bitmap, background, imagebutton

I have a ImageButton with default drawable image. From the code I set up the ImageButton layout size so after this modification the image doesn't cover the whole button because of centerInside scaleType. In the OnClick event I use this code to replace the ImageButton's image.

```
button.setImageBitmap(img);
button.invalidate();
```

The new image is smaller than the old one. After replace the new image appears but the old image parts can be see around the new. How can I force to clear the old image or simply redraw the whole ImageButton to show only the new image?

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPhotoFront"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/front"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/camera" />
```

I tried with android:background="#00000000" but has no effect.
The repaint works only if I don't set up background and leave the default gray button layer.

Comment: android:background="@null"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
android:background="@null"
```

Also note that you are setting two different properties. setImageBitmap is not the corresponding method for android:background

```
    b.setBackground(drawable)
    b.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this also. I need background property for set it to transparent and need an image on it which doesn't cover the whole button. The problem is that the new image doesn't overlap the old one and some parts of the old are leaved visible.

Comment: I've figured out a workaround. Not beautiful but works. I created 1x1 pixel size black color png file and put it into drawables. I used this as background instead of a color. In this case Android has to scale this image and this force the expected repaint when I change the front image of the ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your

```
android:src="@drawable/camera"
```

image file does not have a transparent background. Use Photoshop or GIMP or something similar, cut out your image and put it on a transparent background.